# WebDriverIO/Selenium: unable to start chromedriver with error expecting Chrome version 90

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I am unable to start chromedriver session with the following error:

```
[0-0] 2021-04-14T02:07:34.751Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to status 33
[0-0] 2021-04-14T02:07:34.751Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to session not created: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90
Current browser version is 89.0.4389.114 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'andisan-GL62M-7RDX', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-70-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5646652bde89 <unknown>
```

I am using WebDriverIO 6 and `chromedriver` package version 89.0.0

```
...
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.11.0",
    "chromedriver": "^89.0.0",
    "webdriverio": "^6.11.0"
...
```

As far as I know Chrome 90 is still in beta, so probably that error message is misleading. Any clues on why this happened, and how to solve it?

Comment: You have a mismatch between chomedriver and the chrome version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a temporary issue with `standalone-service` package and it downloads the wrong driver version. So, to solve that you can just set a specific driver version that should be aligned with your browser version (in your case it's 89.0.4389.114).

In the `wdio.conf.js` file

```
export.config = {
    // ...
    services: [
        ['selenium-standalone', { drivers: { chrome: '89.0.4389.114' } }]
    ],
    // ...
};
```